# Check if user auth id exist in firebase database before navigating to a new page

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After a user sign in successfully, I want to use the User UID to verify the user has selected the right school, I have been able to achieve this task, but the problem is, I have to click the login button twice before an action takes effect.

```
var sbmit = document.getElementById("submit");
sbmit.onclick = function (e) {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var s = document.getElementById("school");
  var school = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (school == null || school == "") {
    alert("Please select your school")
    return false;
  } else if (email == null || email == "") {
    alert('email can\'t be empty')
    return false;
  } else if (password == null || password == "") {
    alert("Password ca\'t be empty")
    return false;
  } else {
    toggleSignIn();
//After signing in, use the user auth id to check if the user exist in the selected school
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        ref = database.ref('/schools/')
        userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

        ref.child(school).orderByChild("AuthID").equalTo(userId).once("value", snapshot => {

          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            document.location.href = "/Result"
          } else {
            alert("You have selected the wrong school")
          }

        });

      }
    });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very unusual to have an `onAuthStateChanged` listener in a click handler like that. More likely you want something like:

```
    ...
  } else {
    toggleSignIn();
    ref = database.ref('/schools/')
    userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    ref.child(school).orderByChild("AuthID").equalTo(userId).once("value", snapshot => {

      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        document.location.href = "/Result"
      } else {
        alert("You have selected the wrong school")
      }
    });
  }
```

By the way: if you can look up the school for the user with a query, is there any specific reason why you don't simply prepopulate that value for them in the form?

Comment: alright, I think I have to handle the Auth on the first page, then on the second I can allow students to select their school then I will the user id to verify if they exist in the chosen school.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a flaw. `onAuthStateChanged` listener is attached every time the button is clicked. This could add multiple listeners and the same code triggered multiple times after each repeated click. `onAuthStateChanged` listener should be attached only once when the document is loaded. Your code should be something like:

```
var sbmit = document.getElementById("submit");

sbmit.onclick = function (e) {
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var s = document.getElementById("school");
  var school = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (school == null || school == "") {
    alert("Please select your school")
    return false;
  } else if (email == null || email == "") {
    alert('email can\'t be empty')
    return false;
  } else if (password == null || password == "") {
    alert("Password ca\'t be empty")
    return false;
  } else {
    toggleSignIn();
  }
}

document.onload = function () {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      ref = database.ref('/schools/')
      userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

      ref.child(school).orderByChild("AuthID").equalTo(userId).once("value", snapshot => {

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          document.location.href = "/Result"
        } else {
          alert("You have selected the wrong school")
        }

      });

    }
  });
}
```

I assume `toggleSignIn()` function is used to sign in and will change the firebase AuthState on successful sign in.